# Android ViewPager2 how to retrieve the fragment onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-viewpager2

ViewPager release 1.0.0 version

For a normal RecyclerView, `holder.itemView` gives me the view currently binding/ rendering.

However, FragmentStateAdapter's `holder.itemView` only gives me a FrameLayout

My ViewPager adapater:

```
class MyFragmentStateAdapter(activity: FragmentActivity) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {
    var items = mutableListOf<String>()
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): MyPageFragment {
        val itemText = items[position]
        return MyPageFragment.create(itemText)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: FragmentViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        val fragment = ??? as MyRefreshableInterface
        fragment.refresh()
    }

    fun update(mutableListOf: MutableList<String>) {
        this.items = mutableListOf
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Context**

I have a small and fix number of tabs displaying different information section of a user profile. Upon certain events, I need to refresh AUTOMATICALLY all the tabs ASAP. In other words, I need to refresh the currently-hidden tabs besides the current tab user is looking at.

ASAP = the next time user visits a currently-hidden tab. User goes there, first thing they see is a loading animation. That's good

Why not immediately?

Because hidden fragments could be detached/ destroyed. User is not looking at the right now anyway. Keeping all the fragments in the memory is also expensive

When user navigates to previous hidden tab say *Addresses*, `onBindViewHolder` will be triggered (This is great compared to ViewPager 1) However, the gap is that I have no reference of the currently-selected fragment

**Other findings**

I've already try referencing `fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager.fragments` but it seems to have maximum of 4 fragments whereas I have 6 fragments/ pages, for the sake of testing

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking 2 different things.

> I need to refresh automatically all the tabs. In other words, I need to refresh the currently-hidden tabs besides the current tab user is looking at.

and

> When user navigates to previous hidden tab say Addresses, onBindViewHolder will be triggered.

You are trying to do the update when displayed on this second item.

---

This "Update when displayed" is easy with viewpager2, when a Fragment is displayed the Fragment is brought up to lifecycle state "Resumed" from "Started".

Thus create an `update` method in each Fragment and then in the Fragments `onResume` method call the `update` method.

(This is what I do in my App)

**Update:**
The docs on this behaviour is bad in viewpager2, the best I can find is the comment in the source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.java#634 of

> /**
>        * Pauses (STARTED) all Fragments that are attached and not a primary item.
>        * Keeps primary item Fragment RESUMED.
>        */

Or the release notes https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha06

> FragmentStateAdapter: non-primary-item Fragments are capped at STARTED, and their menuVisibility is set to false.

Viewpager 1 in Androidx has been updated with `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` to match the behaviour of Viewpager2
See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT

---

The "Update all Fragments" is bit harder but I believe you can do the following (sorry my Kotlin is not up to scratch to give code example.

In the Adapter Constructor create and store a List of the Fragments (Not just itemText)
e.g. foreach item in items add to list of Fragments MyPageFragment.create(itemText)

Then in `createFragment` just return the Fragment from the correct position of the list.
e.g. `return fragments[position]`

Then in your adapter `update` you iterate over all items in your List of Fragements calling `update` on each Fragment.

(This is basically maintaining your own list of Fragments in the adapter instead of creating them on the fly when `createFragment` is called)

**Update:**
As noted in the comments this is less than ideal and breaks the Fragment lifecycle concepts and efficiency of Viewpager2, the update in `onResume` of Fragment is better.

Comment: In ViewPager 1, `onResume` is often not call. Can you point me to the doc where it says `onResume` will be called in ViewPager2? *In the Adapter Constructor create and store a List of the Fragments* is expensive and fragile

Comment: So the docs are bad on this but if you look at the release notes https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha06 "FragmentStateAdapter: non-primary-item Fragments are capped at STARTED, and their menuVisibility is set to false."  Also viewpager1 has been updated to match this behaviour and is better documented See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter#FragmentStatePagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20int) with `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`

Comment: Viewpager1 used to bring all fragments up to `Resumed` but in Androidx that has been deprecated as it breaks the lifecycle concept and `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` is the only option as it matches viewpager2's behaviour.